# nginx - parsing continues after return

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to deny bingbot access to /wp-admin and /wp-login.php, but I'm having trouble with my nginx configuration. I started with the following:

```
location ~ /(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "(alltheweb|baidu|bingbot|googlebot|msnbot|slurp)") {
        return 403;
        break;
    }
}

# Allow any php files to run
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php/php.socket;
}
```

This works just fine for blocking bingbot, but it also doesn't execute `wp-login.php`; it treats it like a static file. I thought "Alright, you don't fall through to further location blocks", so I duplicated the php code into the higher one:

```
location ~ /(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "(alltheweb|baidu|bingbot|googlebot|msnbot|slurp)") {
        return 403;
        break;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php/php.socket;
    }
}

# Allow any php files to run
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php/php.socket;
}
```

This enables me to login again instead of download `wp-login.php`, but now bingbot is getting an HTTP 200 OK again!  How do I selectively return 403 or the php handler properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "(alltheweb|baidu|bingbot|googlebot|msnbot|slurp)") {
    location ~ /(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

However, you may want to set up something like:

```
location /spider_blocked {
    return 403;
}

if ($http_user_agent ~* "(alltheweb|baidu|bingbot|googlebot|msnbot|slurp)") {
    rewrite ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) /spider_blocked redirect;
}
```

Basically, what you are doing is setting up a special catch URL for nginx, and doing a redirect on specific urls accessed by specific user agents and redirecting it to the special catch URL to get blocked.